# JavaScript ООП классы

Tags: javascript

Написать класс, который принимает строку и разделитель и возвращает массив подстрок, разбитых с помощью указанного разделителя.
Например: строка “10/08/2020”, разделитель “/”, результат: “10”, “08”, “2020”.

Моя попытка, но он ничего не выводит:

```
class String{
    separator_strings(string1, separator){
        let newText = "";
            if(separator in string1){
                newText += string1;  
                newText += " "; 
            }
            else{
                alert(string1)
            }

        }
    }

let string = new String
string.separator_strings("10/08/10", "/")
```

Могли бы вы помочь с этим

Comment: Очень плохая идея называть класс String. Это встроенный класс в JS

Comment: Во-первых, соглашусь с коментатором выше, называть клас String нельзя, потому что такой клас уже существует в самом JavaScript. Во вторых, чтобы функция(метод) вернули какое то значение, нужно воспользоваться оператором return.

Comment: В-третьих, в задании написана какая-то бессмыслица. Что значит «написать класс который … возвращает …»? Возвращают что-то функции (или методы). А класс по определению должен возвращать объект — экземпляр класса.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Воспользуйся методом строки split

```
class Separator {
    separateString (str){
    return str.split('/')
  }
}


const s = new Separator();

const result = s.separateString("10/08/2020");

console.log(result) // ["10", "08", "2020"]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: спасибо большое